# Share session between Laravel and nodejs through Redis

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis

I've encountered some weird request.

I have to share session data between nodejs and php.So I figured I could use Redis.

I can successfully read the data. However, there are two major problems in the process;

1.The data I read is something like `"s:8560:"a:4:{.........;s:1:"0";}}";"`(php-serialized) However, the length `8560` is not correct, what I measured is `8546`. and even the entire string is `8556` in length.

2.It seems there is some kind of lock on the field set by laravel. I could not override any of the data.

I mean is it supposed to that I cant modify the field set by laravel (write lock or something)? Or am I doing the wrong way. And after I read tons documentations of php serialization, I still couldn't figure out why the lengths do not match.

TYIA

Comment: 1. Redis expects strings and strings only. Use `JSON.stringify / JSON.parse` or the equivalent in php. 2. Redis has no concept of write-locks as you describe. May I suggest using the Redis Commandline to try changing the 'field'? Divide-and-conquer.